# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I ran into a very strange problem, I was running a very old code with tensorflow 1.15-gpu, so I pulled the official image ready to test the code, the image is as follows: **tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5-gpu**, and my gpu driver is:
Fri Mar 15 16:08:38 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07             Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000               Off | 00000000:00:10.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   34C    P8              17W / 230W |   1954MiB / 24564MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    255326      C   /bin/python3                               1948MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
But the code reports the following error:

```
2024-03-15 16:10:38.184546: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
  0%|                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 415, in <module>
    fire.Fire(train)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 143, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 482, in _Fire
    target=component.__name__)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 693, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 377, in train
    matlab_engine)
  File "train.py", line 184, in train_run
    batch_P_graphs_tuple = model(batch_A_graphs_tuple)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wjt/AI4solver/learning-amg_old/graph_net_model.py", line 48, in _build
    latent = self._encoder(input_op)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wjt/AI4solver/learning-amg_old/graph_net_model.py", line 121, in _build
    return self._network(inputs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_nets/modules.py", line 366, in _build
    edges=self._edge_model(graph.edges),
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graph_nets/_base.py", line 112, in _build
    return self._model(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/sequential.py", line 103, in _build
    net = layer(*net)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/nets/mlp.py", line 167, in _build
    net = self._layers[layer_id](net)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self._call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 420, in _call
    outputs, subgraph_name_scope = self._template(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 669, in __call__
    return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/template.py", line 608, in _call_func
    result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/base.py", line 228, in _build_wrapper
    output = self._build(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sonnet/python/modules/basic.py", line 285, in _build
    outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, self._w)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2754, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 6126, in mat_mul
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(229376, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=229376, n=64, k=3 [Op:MatMul] name: EncodeProcessDecodeNonRecurrent/MLPGraphIndependent/graph_independent/edge_model/sequential/mlp/linear_0/MatMul/
```

The error showed that tensorflow's MatMul had an error, so I wrote a test code to test it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf_config =  tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution(config=tf_config)
# with np.float64
print('with np.float64:')
matrix_a = np.random.rand(2000, 3).astype(np.float64)
matrix_b = np.random.rand(3, 64).astype(np.float64)

tensor_a = tf.constant(matrix_a)
tensor_b = tf.constant(matrix_b)
result = tf.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)
print("It's OK!",result.numpy().shape)
```

The results of the run are:

```
It's OK! (2000, 64)
```

So I continued the test by making the matrix size larger:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf_config =  tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution(config=tf_config)
# with np.float64
print('with np.float64:')
matrix_a = np.random.rand(20000, 3).astype(np.float64)
matrix_b = np.random.rand(3, 64).astype(np.float64)

tensor_a = tf.constant(matrix_a)
tensor_b = tf.constant(matrix_b)
result = tf.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)
print("It's OK!",result.numpy().shape)
```

The result is an error and the part output is as follows:

```
2024-03-15 16:23:36.331883: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    result = tf.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2754, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 6126, in mat_mul
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(20000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=20000, n=64, k=3 [Op:MatMul] name: MatMul/
```

Interestingly, if you convert np.float64 to np.float32, for a.shape=(2000, 3) you will also report an error with the following result:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(2000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=2000, n=64, k=3 [Op:MatMul] name: MatMul/
```

What is the reason for this?
In the meantime, I did the following experiment:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() 

matrix_a = np.random.rand(20000, 3).astype(np.float64)
matrix_b = np.random.rand(3, 64).astype(np.float64)

tensor_a = tf.constant(matrix_a)
tensor_b = tf.constant(matrix_b)
result = tf.matmul(tensor_a, tensor_b)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print("It's OK!",sess.run(result).shape)
```

Get:

```
It's OK! (20000, 64)
```

When I continue to increase the size, I get the following complete error:

```
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
2024-03-15 16:21:52.847732: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2024-03-15 16:21:52.861303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.861421: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA RTX A5000 major: 8 minor: 6 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.695
pciBusID: 0000:00:10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.861640: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.862682: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.863552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.863828: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.864947: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.865747: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.868207: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2024-03-15 16:21:52.868318: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.868449: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.868514: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.868810: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2024-03-15 16:21:52.874520: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3695995000 Hz
2024-03-15 16:21:52.875274: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x224cb30 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2024-03-15 16:21:52.875298: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2024-03-15 16:21:52.930606: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.930867: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2240ed0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2024-03-15 16:21:52.930898: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA RTX A5000, Compute Capability 8.6
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931101: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931197: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA RTX A5000 major: 8 minor: 6 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.695
pciBusID: 0000:00:10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931235: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931252: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931261: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931505: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931635: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931825: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931832: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2024-03-15 16:21:52.931913: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.932011: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2024-03-15 16:21:52.932097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22837 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA RTX A5000, pci bus id: 0000:00:10.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2024-03-15 16:21:54.009361: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2024-03-15 16:21:54.230076: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(200000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=200000, n=64, k=3
         [[{{node MatMul}}]]
  (1) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(200000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=200000, n=64, k=3
         [[{{node MatMul}}]]
         [[MatMul/_1]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("It's OK!",sess.run(result).shape)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(200000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=200000, n=64, k=3
         [[node MatMul (defined at /data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
  (1) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(200000, 3), b.shape=(3, 64), m=200000, n=64, k=3
         [[node MatMul (defined at /data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
         [[MatMul/_1]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'MatMul':
  File "test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = tf.matmul(tensor_a, tensor_b)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2754, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 6136, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/wjt/anaconda3/envs/AIslv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Can anyone help me?